# Saving inputted history in a command line program (under capability mode)

Tags: history, freebsd, capability

The following code works exactly as expected if the cap_enter line is removed.  However I'd like to make sure my program runs in capability mode.

I've distilled this program down from a 4000+ line bigger program into a minimal example.

When I use [ktrace](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ktrace%281%29) to run the program and them kdump the output I see the following line:

> 52225 tests    RET   open -1 errno 94 Not permitted in capability mode

around the point I wanted the history.

Is it possible to both use capability mode and keep history ?

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <histedit.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/capsicum.h>

static const char* promptstr = "";

static const char * prompt(EditLine *e __unused) {
    return promptstr;
}
-
int
main(int argc __unused, char **argv)
{

    History *inhistory;
    EditLine *el;
    HistEvent ev;

    inhistory = history_init();
    el = el_init(argv[0], stdin, stdout, stderr);
    el_set(el, EL_PROMPT, &prompt);
    el_set(el, EL_EDITOR, "emacs");
    el_set(el, EL_SIGNAL, 1);
    el_set(el, EL_HIST, history, inhistory);
    el_source(el, NULL);
    history(inhistory, &ev, H_SETSIZE, 50);
    if (inhistory == 0)
        err(1, "Could not initalize history");

    if (cap_enter() < 0)
        err(1, "unable to enter capability mode");

    for (;;) {
        const char* havestr;
        int inputsz;

        havestr = el_gets(el, &inputsz);
        if (havestr == NULL)
            exit(0);
        if (inputsz > 0)
            history(inhistory, &ev, H_ENTER, havestr);
        if (*havestr == '.')
            break;
    }

    history(inhistory, &ev, H_SAVE, "/tmp/myhistory");

    history_end(inhistory);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to open any file when in capability mode.  The best way to solve it would be to extend history() API to make it possible to pass a file descriptor instead of path; you would then first open the history file, then call cap_enter(), and then write the history using file descriptor opened in the first step.

A workaround would be to open the history file, then call cap_enter(), and then save the history "by hand", using loop obtaining history entries (H_FIRST or H_NEXT) and saving to the file.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is H_SAVE_FP which saves files to an opened file pointer.

The code then looks like:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("historyfile", "w");
...
cap_enter();
...
history(inhistory, &ev, H_SAVE_FP, fp);
```